# Download Landsat data from Google Earth Engine for the continental United States

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat, download

I need to download one image of the Landsat 7 NDVI 32 day from Google Earth Engine for the continental United States. Just this specific one image from 2005-08-13 to 2005-09-14. Please see my code below:

```js
//Import Landsat Image
var L7200508NDVI = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LE7_L1T_32DAY_NDVI')
.filterDate('2005-08-13', '2005-09-14')
.filterBounds(region);

print('L7200508NDVI', L7200508NDVI);
Map.addLayer(L7200508NDVI);

// Load a region representing the United States //this doesn't work as my boundary
var region = ee.FeatureCollection('ft:1tdSwUL7MVpOauSgRzqVTOwdfy17KDbw-1d9omPw')
.filter(ee.Filter.eq('Country', 'United States'));
Map.addLayer(region);

// Create a small area to test: geometry representing an export region.
var geometry = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([116.2621, 39.8412, 116.4849, 40.01236]);

// Export the image, specifying scale and region.
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: L7200508NDVI,
  description: 'imageToDriveExample',
  scale: 30,
  region: geometry,
  maxPixels:1e11
});
```

1. If I use the test geometry I got the error:

> Error: Invalid argument: 'image' must be of type Image.

2. I am not sure how to create a polygon just right for the continental United States. Or do I need import a polygon from my ArcGIS layer?

Comment: does the same work for Landsat8 also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are working with an ImageCollection, which contains overlapping images. For export you need a single image. One way to go from an ImageCollection to an image is use a simple reducer such as taking the mean of the overlapping parts.

To mask everything outside the continental `clip` the image to the region.

Export does not support MultiPolygons. But you can use the bounding box of your region and skip the empty tiles (i.e. the parts you have masked with `clip`).

```js
// Load a region representing the United States //this doesn't work as my boundary
var region = ee.FeatureCollection('ft:1tdSwUL7MVpOauSgRzqVTOwdfy17KDbw-1d9omPw')
.filter(ee.Filter.eq('Country', 'United States'));

//Import Landsat Image
var L7200508NDVI = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LE7_L1T_32DAY_NDVI')
  // .filterDate('2005-08-13', '2005-09-14')
  .filterBounds(region);

print('L7200508NDVI', L7200508NDVI);

Map.addLayer(L7200508NDVI.mean().clip(region));

// Export the image, specifying scale and region.
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: L7200508NDVI.mean().clip(region),
  description: 'imageToDriveExample',
  scale: 30,
  region: region.geometry().bounds(),
  maxPixels:1e11,
  skipEmptyTiles: true
});
```

Comment: Hi, Kersten. Thank you so much for answering. I think I got it for my question 1 about the difference between image and image collection. But for the boundary issue, with your revised code, I think it still clipped the image to the whole U.S. (including Alaska). I saw this from the display by this code line: Map.addLayer(L7200508NDVI.mean().clip(region)); So the bounding box still included Alaska when Export.image.to Drive. I was wondering, is there a way to get rid of Alaska?

Comment: You need to edit the geometry of the Feature you imported to remove alaska or possibly use a different feature collection that allows the selection by state.

Comment: Oh, right. Thanks. I draw a polygon around the continental US and imported it as the "region" in the Export.image.toDrive. Everything else is the same. And I got the exact images with continental US that I want. Thanks again, Kersten.

Answer (score 0):

```
var S2 = imageCollection
.filterMetadata('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 'less_than', 100)
.filterDate ('1999-08-2','2000-08-20')
.filterBounds(table).select(['B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7'])
.sort('CLOUD_COVER') 
.mosaic()
//.first();
print(S2)
var clipimage = S2.clip(table)
Map.addLayer(clipimage)
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: clipimage,
  scale: 30,
  description: 'Landsat7',
  region: table,
  maxPixels: 1e11
});
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Answers should be more than code. This is especially true when the Question has an Answer that was accepted many years previously. What is it about this Answer that addresses the Question not addressed by the existing Answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
//var image = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR")
Map.addLayer(table)
var S2 = imageCollection
.filterMetadata('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 'less_than',10)
.filterDate ('2022-10-1','2022-10-25')
.filterBounds(table).select(['B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7', 'B8'])
.sort('CLOUD_COVER') 
.mosaic()
//.first();
print(S2)
var clipimage = S2.clip(table)
Map.addLayer(clipimage)
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: clipimage,
  scale: 10,
  description: 'TTS_Oct',
  region: table,
  maxPixels: 1E10
});
```

Comment: Explanations are welcomed