# Finding metadata for Fusion Table used in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-fusion-tables

I'm just starting to learn GEE, and I see a number of places use a Fusion Table that has polygons of world countries. It's used in the Google Earth Engine [manual](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/feature_collections), [tutorials](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/tutorial_forest_03), and questions on [stackexchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/287004/download-landsat-data-from-google-earth-engine-for-the-continental-united-states). The Fusion Table is `ft:1tdSwUL7MVpOauSgRzqVTOwdfy17KDbw-1d9omPw` and can (currently) be found [here](https://fusiontables.google.com/DataSource?docid=1tdSwUL7MVpOauSgRzqVTOwdfy17KDbw-1d9omPw). But I can't find any reasonable metadata for it. I've tried:

1. getting the metadata within GEE:

   ```
   // Country Fusion Table
   var countries =  ee.FeatureCollection('ft:1tdSwUL7MVpOauSgRzqVTOwdfy17KDbw-1d9omPw');

   // Get a list of all metadata properties.
   var properties = countries.propertyNames();
   print('Metadata properties: ', properties); // ee.List of metadata properties

   // Get a specific metadata property.
   var name = countries.get('name');
   print(name); // ee.Number
   var docid = countries.get('DocID');
   print(docid);
   ```

   But all that it returns is:

   ```
   Metadata properties: 
   ["name","DocID"]
      0: name
      1: DocID
   Countries.csv
   1tdSwUL7MVpOauSgRzqVTOwdfy17KDbw-1d9omPw
   ```
2. Going directly to the [Fusion Table](https://fusiontables.google.com/DataSource?docid=1tdSwUL7MVpOauSgRzqVTOwdfy17KDbw-1d9omPw) and going to file > about, which shows this:

   [image]

   Which still says nothing of where the info actually comes from or who created it.

So how do I find out more info about this particular dataset, and how do I evaluate the data quality of Fusion Tables more generally?

Comment: It looks like a good alternative would be to simply use a different dataset: `ee.FeatureCollection("USDOS/LSIB/2013")` from [here][1], but that doesn't answer the original question. 

[1] https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/USDOS_LSIB_2013

Comment: Yes, may be this could be the answer, as @filups21 says, use [this](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/USDOS_LSIB_2013) or [this](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/USDOS_LSIB_SIMPLE_2017). Take in consideration that Fusion Tables has an [expire date](https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/9185417)

Answer (score 0):

I also faced a similar challenge but after keen research, I discovered that Google dropped Fusion Tables with their visualization capabilities. Alternative recommendations can be found [here](https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/9185417?hl=en),